# webpack-pug js function is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack, pug

Im new to webpack and pug . Working on a small task  and

- I wrote a function dropDown() in drop.js  exported it in index.js file,
- tried to put it in PUG file
  but:
- console writing wether 'function is not defined' or f'unction is not a function'.
- Please could anyone help me to solve that problem with correct defining js function

here is the link to my webpack.config
[enter link description here](https://github.com/elmira26/webpack_1st_project/blob/main/webpack.config.js)

here is my json file
[enter link description here](https://github.com/elmira26/webpack_1st_project/blob/main/package.json)

in PUG file i use function like this:

```
 .searchbox-drop
    button(href="#" data-dropdown='drop1' onclick='dropDown()' aria-controls='drop1' aria-expanded=false class='dropbtn') Вce
      +image('triangle','searchbox-drop__icon' )
```

in index.js

```
import $ from "jquery";
import 'bootstrap';
import './styles/index.scss';
import {dropDown} from './drop.js';





window.dropDown = dropDown();
```

in drop.js

```
export function dropDown(){ 
function show() {
  document.getElementById('myDropdown').classList.toggle('show');
}

//close dropdown id the user cliks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e){
if(!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')){
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById('myDropdown');
    if(myDropdown.classList.contains('show')){
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

}

here is part of PUG plugin  in CONFIG file:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
filename: 'index.pug' ,
minify: false,
scriptloading:'blocking',
inject:'body'
}),
new HtmlWebpackPugPlugin()
```

and here is index.pug

```
include pug/libs/_libs
include pug/_mixins

doctype html
html(lang='en')
include pug/_head
body
include pug/_header
block content
```

i dont know what i done, but now i even got this error when click on btn[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nomIV.png)

Comment: Where do you import your `pug` file?

Comment: @StevenSpungin I'm sorry not sure what do you mean ? in index.pug file? or you mean in webpack.config?

Comment: Yes, the error seems to be the way you import your pug file.

Comment: @StevenSpungin ill put snippets of config and index.pug files in my post in few mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to assign the function without invoking it.

```js
window.dropDown = dropDown;
```

Perhaps this is what you want...

```
export function dropDown() {
document.getElementById('myDropdown').classList.toggle('show');
}

//close dropdown id the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e){
if(!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')){
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById('myDropdown');
    if(myDropdown.classList.contains('show')){
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried, nothing happened, neither function working and nothing in console

Comment: if i type in dropDown() in console, it says undefined

Comment: In your posted example, when you assign `= dropdown()`, you are assigning the return value of the function, and that is `undefined`.

Comment: To test the module is invoked, next to it add `window.hello = 'world';` and see what your console says for `window.hello`.

Comment: I got even different error now, when i click the button .But i havn't changed anything..

Comment: content.js:243 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index.
    at Content.isSelection (chrome-extension://hiidjliailpkjeigakikbfedlfijngih/js/content.js:243:53)
    at Content.handleSelection (chrome-extension://hiidjliailpkjeigakikbfedlfijngih/js/content.js:235:14)
isSelection @ content.js:243
handleSelection @ content.js:235

Comment: yes, now its working, and the problem is your function implementation.  it seems nothing is selected yet your code is trying access it.

Comment: what does console log for `document.getElementById('myDropdown')` show?  Im not really sure what you want to happen on button click.  It seems you should be installing the click handler outside the function.

Comment: see updated solution.

Comment: Thank you soooo much, yes were right, and also changed my code a little bit. ill post and answer with right code that works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Steven I finally made few changes that solved an issue.
in index.js it goes like :

```
import $ from "jquery";
import 'bootstrap';
import './styles/index.scss';
import {show} from './drop.js';





window.show= show;
window.onclick = function(e){
if(!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')){
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById('myDropdown');
    if(myDropdown.classList.contains('show')){
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

and in index.pug:

```
 onclick = 'show()'
```